# Resource estimation for Trotterisation always outputs a 0 T-gate cost?

Tags: q#

I have been working with q# for a couple weeks now, and I'm interested in resource estimation for quantum chemistry.

Using the example programs provided, such as "GetGateCount" on a variety of molecules (also provided by the examples) I always get a 0  T gate count for Trotterisation. Qubitization and Optimized Qubitization seem to be working fine.

This was also the case when I added resource estimation to a different example program provided, "MolecularHydrogenGUI" with the info provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/machines/resources-estimator.

Any help would be appreciated, I was wondering if this is a recent bug?

Comment: Please share code that you have already tried and where you are getting stuck so we can better assist you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ResourceEstimator outputs the literal gate counts - the number of times each gate has been invoked in the code. It provides two separate gate counts for T gates and arbitrary rotation gates, and it does not perform gate synthesis to convert arbitrary rotations into sequences of primitive gates including T gates.

I suspect the other two algorithms use both arbitrary rotations and T gates explicitly, and Trotterization uses only rotations, so the T gate count shows as 0, even though running this code on a real device would definitely require T gates. I have not looked into the code to confirm this, though.

The script used to produce the graphs for the chemistry gate counts in the samples [uses the following approximation](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/blob/master/samples/chemistry/GetGateCount/Out-Plot.ps1#L50) of T gate count using ResourceEstimator reports:

```
TotalTCount = TCount - 4 * log2( 0.001 / RotationsCount) * RotationsCount
```