# Information needed to reproduce T-Costs for quantum chemistry as provided in the simulating nature article

Tags: q#

The article I was referring to in the title is: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/quantum/2018/12/04/simulating-nature-with-the-new-microsoft-quantum-development-kit-chemistry-library/  which provides resource estimates for certain metrics for different molecules with Trotterisation, Qubitization, and Optimized Qubitization.

I would like to reproduce some of this data, and I have been using the example program "GetGateCount" to do so. Trotterisation seems to have a problem with T-costs, see my question here for more: [Resource estimation for Trotterisation always outputs a 0 T-gate cost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619381/resource-estimation-for-trotterisation-always-outputs-a-0-t-gate-cost)

My question here is what information do I need to reproduce the same values as provided in the article? I am using robust phase estimation (is this what was used for the article?), in which the run time is very dependent on the bits of precision. To approximately get the same T-cost as in the article for qubitization, I found 3 bits of precision worked best, (but this leads to a large uncertainty on the phase  and energy? as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.characterization.robustphaseestimation). For comparison, I calculated that chemical accuracy for molecular hydrogen would require approx 13 bits of precision with robust phase estimation.

Another related question is regarding the difference between Qubitization and Optimized Qubitization. The article explains that Optimized should have a minimized T-cost, and the graph provided shows this to be the case across the molecules investigated. Contrary to this, I find, using the same example program "GetGateCount", that the Qubitization oracle is consistently "resource estimated" to have a lower T-cost as compared to the Optimized Qubitization oracle. This does not seem to be dependent on the additional parameter for Optimized, "targetError", as it causes only a minimal change to the T-cost when varied across a wide range.

An example of my results for energy estimation on LiH (not just a single application of the oracle) is included below:

```
Gate Count results on ..\IntegralData\yaml\LiHdata\integrals_lih_sto-3g_0.800.nw.out.yaml
by Trotter with 12 spin-orbitals. It took 4335 ms.
Gate count statistics:

    # T:0,
    # Rotations:90756,
    # CNOT:559872,

Gate Count results on ..\IntegralData\yaml\LiHdata\integrals_lih_sto-3g_0.800.nw.out.yaml
by Qubitization with 12 spin-orbitals. It took 14012 ms.
Gate count statistics:

    # T:191376,
    # Rotations:315252,
    # CNOT:1241136,

Gate Count results on ..\IntegralData\yaml\LiHdata\integrals_lih_sto-3g_0.800.nw.out.yaml
by Optimized Qubitization with 12 spin-orbitals. It took 44345 ms.
Gate count statistics:

    # T:711360,
    # Rotations:1620,
    # CNOT:2118168
```

See Trotter with 0 cost, and the higher T cost of Optimized as compared to non-optimized.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the [`GetGateCount` sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/samples/chemistry/GetGateCount) was used to generate the plots in that figure.
The [`Operations.qs` source file](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/blob/master/samples/chemistry/GetGateCount/Operation.qs) in that sample shows the details of what each different plot represents; in particular, the Trotter, Qubitization and Optimized Qubitization results are for a single step of each algorithm. As you note, the number of steps required depends on the relevant chemical accuracy.

Though that's not a level of detail that we went into for that post, the follow-up [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01131v1) goes into a lot more detail about that kind of comparison. All the source code used to generate that paper has been attached at https://arxiv.org/src/1904.01131v1/anc, along with a Dockerfile that can be used to reproduce the exact software environment.

With respect to your other question, the resources estimator's  count reports the number `T` operation calls required excluding used to decompose `R` calls. Thus, the optimized qubitization method trades off some `T` calls for a dramatic saving in the number of rotations that must be decomposed.